# Use field resolver or table join to retrieve relation depending on the query | graphql

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

I have two resolvers - `address` to get a single address with the user its owned by and `addresses` to get the addresses of all the addresses with their owners. For the address resolver (and other resolvers I have) it makes sense to retrieve the user by a FieldResolver - however for the adresses resolver I would like to just join all the users in the database and retrieve the data like that.

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour?

My code uses type-graphql:

```
@Resolver(Address)
export class AddressResolver {
  @FieldResolver(() => User)
  async user(
    @Root() address: Address,
    @Ctx() { em }: EmContext): Promise<User | null> {
    console.log("address", address)
    return em.findOne(User, { where: { id: address.user?.id } });
  }

  //Trigger Field resolver here
  @Query(() => Address, { nullable: true })
  address(
    @Arg("id", () => Number) id: number,
    @Ctx() { em }: EmContext
  ): Promise<Address | null> {
    return em.findOneBy(Address, {id});
  }

  //Dont trigger field resolver here as relation is already being loaded
  @Query(() => [Address], { nullable: true })
  addresses(
    @Ctx() { em }: EmContext
  ): Promise<Address[] | null> {
    return em.find(Address, { user: true } });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning all the addresses would be a *query* rather than a field resolver.

In your typeDefs you would have something like:

```
type Address {
  …address scalar fields
  isUser: Boolean
}

type User {
  address: Address
}

type Query {
  addresses: [Address]
}
```

Running the `addresses` query would return an array of `Address` objects.

Comment: But how can I define the addresses query such that it does not trigger the user field resolver and instead performs a join to get the user data?

Comment: You can but it's an anti-pattern. 1) Perform the join and return the fields from both tables. 2) In your user field resolver, check to see if the user fields are all included in the parent object. 3) If they are, return them directly. 4) If not, perform the lookup to find the user. Downside is that if the user object changes then this code will also need to change.